# Deleting an item in django after clicking a button in a pop up

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I want to create a pop up which opens up clicking the button 'Dissolve'. The pop up should say: 'Are you sure you want to delete this field?' and have two buttons: Okay and Cancel. If Cancel is chosen it should simply close the pop up. If Okay is clicked, it should redirect to the previous page and delete that job on the previous page's table.

My current code for the button is:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Dissolve</button>
```

My current code for the job in module.py is:

```
class Job(models.Model):
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
name = models.CharField('Job Name',max_length=128)
# when the job was created
date_created = models.DateTimeField('Date Created', auto_now=True)
# what entity/organization needs this job?
client_organization = models.CharField('What organization do you represent?', max_length=64)
# short description
description = models.TextField('Job Description', max_length=256)
# end product to be delivered
deliverable = models.TextField('Deliverable', max_length=256)
# when Job is due for completion
duedate = models.DateTimeField('Date Due')
# all persons who may be affected by project
#stakeholders = models.TextField('Stakeholders')
# important technical requirements
#additional_information = models.TextField('Additional Information', blank = True)
# budget estimate
#budget = models.CharField('Budget', max_length=64)
# file attachments
#attachments = models.FileField(upload_to='job', blank = True)
creator = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'jobs')
organizations = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, through = 'JobRequest', blank=False, null=True)
#organizations = models.CharField(default="nothing",null=True,max_length = 256)
contact_information = models.CharField('Contact Information', max_length = 256, blank = False, null=True)
skill_required = models.CharField('Volunteer skills required', max_length=256, blank = False, null=True)
hours_day = models.CharField('Number of hours per day', max_length=256, blank = False, null=True)
#  Job is closed after a jr is confirmed
closed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
# some tags to determine what organizations to submit job to
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name = 'jobs')
#categories = models.CharField(default="nothing",null=True, max_length = 256)
status = models.IntegerField(default = 0, choices = ((0, 'Pending'), (1, 'Approved'), (2, 'Disapproved'), (3, 'Closed')))
active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ( 'view_job','Can view Job' ),
        ( 'edit_job','Can edit Job'),
        ( 'is_creator', 'Is a creator of Job')
        )
```

My current code for the previous page's HTML is:

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Your Jobs
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list-group">
      {% for job in jobs %}
      <a class="list-group-item" href="{% url 'job_dash' job.id %}">
        {{ job.name }}
      </a>
      {% endfor %}
      <br>
      <a href = '/job_creation' class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa- 
     plus"></i> Create Job</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: My pop works well. I need help with making a delete function in views.py and writing an onclick javascript function to facilitate deletion of the job.